# I have been getting this Zybook output error, and I am not sure why

Tags: output

I have been completing my Zybooks assignment, however I continue to get an error that my output is incorrect. Has anyone found a solution to this?

I am not sure what is causing this, but I have other programs that have this same issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFvu0.png)